# Same expression but different outcome

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-operator

I was attempting a simple frequency counting function for an ARRAY of vehicles as such:

```
    const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck', 'airplane'];
```

two separate but similar expressions were used: 
Where both, i think, expressed in the same way : if veh not in object it equals 0 else if in obj keep adding one. However, the function using ternary operator gives an obj with vehicle names but all with a value of 0.

1.

```
let sumVeh = data.reduce((obj, veh) => {
  if(!obj[veh]) obj[veh] = 0; 
  obj[veh]++;
  return obj;
}, {})
```

RESULT :

```
{car : 5, truck : 3, bike : 2....}
```

2.

```
let sumVeh = data.reduce((obj, veh) => {
  !obj[veh] ? obj[veh] = 0 : obj[veh]++;
  return obj;
}, {})
```

RESULT :

```
{car : 0, truck : 0, bike : 0....}
```

Why is it doing this?? I just couldn't make sense... Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I think `veh in obj ? obj[veh]++ : obj[veh] = 1` is clearer, I would recommend *never* using a ternary to control side-effects.  Only use them in pure expressions.  You could write it without either a ternary or an `if` like this:  `data.reduce((obj, veh) => ({...obj, [veh]: (obj[veh] || 0) + 1}), {})`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you sir!! Appreciate your thoughtful advice!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions are not equivalent. The ternary operator expression is equivalent to this code:

```
if(!obj[veh]) obj[veh] = 0;
else obj[veh]++;
```

Do you see how this is different than your version 1? `obj[veh]` only ever gets incremented **if it is already a truthy value**. However, it can only either be `undefined` or `0` before that - both falsy values.

The two expressions are not at all equivalent, since version 1 increments `obj[veh]` regardless of the result of the if-statement, whereas version 2 only increments `obj[veh]` in the else condition.

Comment: The solution is to change it to `obj[veh] = 1` in the ternary.

Comment: @Barmar That would solve the problem, but the question was *why* this difference was manifesting itself - personally I find version 1 much more sensible anyway.

Comment: I generally interpret "why doesn't this work?" as "why doesn't this work and how can I fix it?"

Comment: I suspect the OP's actualy confusion is that he intended `!obj[veh]` to mean `obj[veh] === undefined`.

Comment: Using that in version 2 will prevent it from being all 0, but the results will be off by 1.

Comment: @Barmar Probably, but even with that fix they would still need your suggested `obj[veh] = 1`, as the problem is version 1 doesn't use an `else` at all, making the two expressions not at all equivalent like they're stated to be

Comment: @Klaycon much appreciate the response!!! Now it all makes sense!! such a subtle difference but had no idea... Thanks again!